# How do you say "gehen" in an exaggerated way?

Tags: verb

> Ich will mich nicht jeden Tag in die Schule schleppen! Ich bleibe lieber zu Hause und sehe fern.
>
> *I dont want to drag myself to school everyday! I rather stay home and watch television.*

Can I use *sich schleppen* to make it exaggerated?

Comment: Yep, "schleppen" works fine in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mit pejorativer Konnotation:

> Ich will nicht jeden Tag in die Schule latschen.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you want to say.

If you want to stress the fact that you have to walk to school, you can use something like "sich die Füße wundlaufen" or "sich die Hacken ablaufen".
"Sich irgendwo hin schleppen" means that you have a hard time walking (because you're wounded or exhausted, for example).

If you want to point out that being in school is pointless and it doesn't really matter how you got there (e.g., go by car), you'd say something like "sich den Arsch plattsitzen", maybe adding why you feel it's a waste (e.g., "für nichts und wieder nichts" -- for nothing).

Comment: "Sich irgendwo hinschleppen" can actually also imply your lack of motivation to visit said place, in addition to "having a hard time getting there because of injury etc.".
Also "latschen" is a way to say that one walks in an unmotivated way.